# Is there any 'official' list of errata for Nielsen & Chuang?

Tags: resource-request, nielsen-and-chuang

The book [Quantum Computing and Quantum Information](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/quantum-computation-and-quantum-information/01E10196D0A682A6AEFFEA52D53BE9AE) by Nielsen and Chuang is a well-known and celebrated text book that can act as a resource in a wide variety of topics. Of course, in such a vast textbook there might arise small errors.

Its own preface (at least in the $10$th anniversary edition) addresses this as well, and links to the website `http://www.squint.org/qci/` for a list of errata and requests any newly found errors to be send to `qci@squint.org`. Neither links are still functional, let alone maintained.

There is also the [list of errata](http://www.michaelnielsen.org/qcqi/errata/errata/errata.html) to be found on the website of Dr. Nielsen, although this doesn't seem to be maintained anymore either: there is a time-stamp from back in $2014$ and the list refers to the first until the *fifth* print of the book, which is not the last print of the book.

A google search provides some other resources, sometimes PDF documents, which all seem to be one version or another of the list of errata linked above.

**My question is**: Is there (still) an 'official' or 'semi-official' list of errata, preferably for the $10$th anniversary edition, and also preferably still being maintained?

**As a follow up question**, is there also a way to notify the maintainers about any as of yet unnoticed errors?

Comment: Michael Nielsen is on Twitter, might be worth a shot: @michael_nielsen

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Michael Nielsen said the book is not maintained. I asked him on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/michael_nielsen/status/1303374791554940929) .

Comment: Thank you a lot! I actually don't have 'a twitter' so I was hoping for something like this. Makes me think if it is actually a good idea to start maintaining a list of errata...

Comment: I also think an errata list would be a good idea. That old list is definitely not comprehensive.